# Does java uses new String(...) to create dynamic Strings/command line arguments/file IO

Tags: java, string, constructor, command-line-arguments

Consider following piece of code :

```
public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception{

        String  a = "sharmaji";

        String b = args[0];

        System.out.println(a==b);

}
```

Now if i pass the a command line argument as "sharmaji" then a==b returns false. This suggests that java, uses new String(...) argument to create the String.

Is it because java has to read user inputs as bytes and then convert it to String?

Comment: `a == b` would never return true here, since they are clearly different object references as you just assigned a string literal to `a`. How does this demonstrate anything?

Comment: "This suggests that java uses new String(...)" <-- well yes, how would you do otherwise? Although, if you use string concatenation (`+`), it is really a `StringBuilder` that is used internally.

Answer (score 1):

This is because strings created from command line arguments are created in `runtime` and compiler doesn't know anything about them (what values would be passed into the program).

Consider [Example 3.10.5-1. String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html) of JLS for better understanding of how Java uses its internal string "cache".

Answer (score 0):

The argument which you passed is a runtime value and created in heap as new Object , but

`String  a = "sharmaji";`  is a compile time constant and is put in String literal pool.

Think like whenever you pass any string through command line  , then it occurs like this -

```
String args[]={"sharmaji","namaste"};
```

then it will be like -

```
args[0]=new String("sharmaji");

args[1]=new String("namaste");
```

So new Object is created hence its reference cannot be same as you are checking with `==` operator.

But see this case

```
public class TestEx {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        String s="asd";
        String s1[]={"asd","asd1"};
        if(s1[0]==s)
        {
                   System.out.println("true");
                }
                else
                   System.out.println("false");

        }
}
```

Since here the value of array is being initialized at compile time , so the reference for "asd" is same for `s1[0] and s` , prints `TRUE`